# How to fix "must be declared in an enclosing class" error in Deno?

Tags: deno

I compiled my deno app and on one of my servers I get this error:

```
$ ./api                                                        
error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#h1' must be declared in an enclosing class
    at file://$deno$/bundle.js:3004:16
```

two other servers it runs fine.

Bother servers are running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

deno -V is 1.15.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to pass the `-r` flag for recompiling typescript

`$ deno compile --allow-all --unstable -r --no-check --output ./api ./index.ts`

it now runs

Comment: if you had to pass `-r` that leads me to believe you or one of your dependency is using untagged imports so one of the servers is getting a newer version of your deps or something like that, something else to keep an eye out for.